# Required attribute and validation groups

Tags: html, validation

I have several textboxes on the form that are marked with required="required" attribute (html5).
There are two buttons. The first button should cause validation, the second should not.

ValidationGroup doesn't work in this case.

How is it possible to solve this issue?

UPD: To use required attribute is the requirement so I cannot avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type=submit formnovalidate>
```

Submits the form without validation.

Comment: @Elistan sorry, it should be `formnovalidate` instead of `novalidate`.